# OFFSET junto de COUNT(*) retorna nada?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quando faço uma consulta desta forma são me retornado os dados corretamente(No momento 2 linhas):

```
SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY data_noticia DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 2
```

Porém eu preciso saber a quantidade de linhas que essa consulta me retorna então intuitivamente faria assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM noticias ORDER BY data_noticia DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 2
```

Mas fazendo desta forma isso me retorna vazio, qual alternativa eu teria?

Comment: ai é só fazer duas querys, uma pra conta contar e outra pra retornar os dados.

Comment: Aproveite e tire esse * da query, ponha só as colunas que vai realmente usar, se quiser otimizar.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, você quer saber o total dos resultados, ou o total só depois de aplicado o offset? Para cada caso a solução é diferente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não "retorna". `COUNT()` resulta a quantidade total de itens que ele achou que satisfaz a consulta estabelecida. Quantas informações resulta? **Uma**. Só a quantidade total, um único valor. Quando você manda desprezar um valor, já está desprezando tudo o que resultou, então faz todo sentido ter este comportamento. Não faz sentido usar `OFFSET` com `COUNT()`.

Se quer saber quantas linhas a *query* resultou pode fazer isto:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (SELECT 1 FROM noticias ORDER BY data_noticia DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 2) AS resultado;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CountOffset.sql).

Você faz sua *query* e o resultado dela você faz a conta. Lembrando que ele dará um valor até 30. Se tiver mais que 30 sempre será 30.

Não posso garantir que é a melhor forma, mas a base é esta.

Se estiver pegando efetivamente os dados da primeira consulta aí poderá contar quantas linhas foram entregues pelo banco de dados para sua aplicação direta na aplicação. Pode pegar o tamanho do *array* obtido ou pode usar a função [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: Faltou a alternativa que eu teria ?

Comment: Alternativa para que?

Comment: Ele quer fazer um Count em cima do select com offset que ele fez.

Answer (score 2):

A função Count retorna somente uma linha, então não tem como aplicar offset, você vai perder essa linha no seu retorno.

Comment: Como eu faço então ?

Comment: A alternativa é fazer o "select do select": `Select count(*) from SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY data_noticia DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 2;`

Comment: Dicas: use `count(1)` (dá no mesmo e pode ser até mais performático se não houver otimização) e evite fazer `select *`, prefira nomear os campos que quer trazer.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria fazer 2 consultas, usando `sql_calc_found_rows` e `FOUND_ROWS()` para pegar o total de registros, conforme a [**DOC**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) do MYSQL.

```
SELECT sql_calc_found_rows * FROM noticias ORDER BY data_noticia DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 2

SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Dessa forma você não precisa repetir a mesma query com `COUNT(*)`, seriam 2 outputs, um com array dos registros com offset e outro com `array( [found_rows()] => 9 )`.

Comment: Fiz um teste rápido, não sei se está certo, mas voltou 0.

Comment: @Maniero são 2 consultas distintas; testei aqui antes de postar e saiu o resultado esperado. Eu tenho uma classe pro meu BD - na maioria das consultas eu preciso de paginação - então a própria classe faz o cálculo usando esse método que postei.